# Gallery slider is stacking images vertically and not horizontally + keyboard input isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/zdYzg/5/

I'm currently working on a simple gallery in Javascript with keyboard control input to move the gallery images. The jSFiddle shows the code, but for some reason the slider isn't working on jSfiddle, but it is working on my localhost MAMP server.

The problem is I can't get the images in my grid to stop stacking vertically. I've looked at the UL LI css and it seems to be not working and making the li images float vertically on top of each.

Another question of mine is, how can I tell the Javascript's gridSize variable to change for responsive web purposes because 1100 will be too big for some screens?

The Javascript for the slider. 
    $(window).load (function() {

```
 var image = $('img'); 
 var theWidth = image.width();
 var gridSize = -1100;
 var grid;
 var totalWidth = image.length * theWidth; 

$('ul.grid').css({ 
  width: function(){ 
  return totalWidth;     
}    
});

$('#back').click(function() {
if(gridSize - theWidth != -totalWidth) {
  grid = gridSize + 1100;
} else {
  grid = 0;
};
updatePosition();
});

$('#page').click(function(){
if(gridSize != 0) {
  grid = gridSize - 1100;
} else {
  grid =  0;
};
updatePosition();
});


var updatePosition = function() {
$('ul.grid').animate({ "margin-left": (grid)}, 650);
    gridSize = -1100;
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    updatePosition();
}
else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    grid = gridSize + 1100;
}
})

});
```

HTML

```
  <div class="grid-wrap">
   <ul class="grid">
    <li>
        <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/363B3w2S0c3y22100R2D/img1.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/09110S1L2t2X0K0J1d1D/img2.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://f.cl.ly/items/0L152B400u0d0k1g2a1e/img3.png">
    </li>
    </ul>
 </div>

  <div id="btns">
     <div class="forward"></div>
     <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
  .grid-wrap {
     background: #FFF;
     margin: 0 auto;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 600px;
 }
ul.grid li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What about $(document).ready() instead?

Comment: @PsychHalf Oh, weird. I've tried using the latest jQuery build it offers, and still nothing. :/

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks! Now everything isn't vertically stacking, now I just gotta figure out the rwd stuff and the keyboard input :P

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: gridWith is not defined`

Comment: @Monstr92 very good it works now, worth a vote up?

Comment: @PsychHalf http://jsfiddle.net/zdYzg/12/ Here's fixed jsFiddle. The slider actually works, but there's still bugs for the keyboard input.